# Placing div's with float

Tags: html, django, css, django-templates

I have one big list of dictionaries in django view as follows:

```
'description': [
        {
            'name': 'Onderdelen',
            'good': ['Motor', 'Versnellingsbak', 'Koppeling', 'Carburatie - injectie - Diesel injectie + verstuivers'],
            'trace_of_use': ['Differentieel', 'Batterij', 'Radiator', 'Alternator', 'Startmotor'],
            'to_repair': ['Cardanhoezen', 'Uitlaat', 'Aandrijfriemen van accessoires'],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Wielen en banden',
            'good': ['Staat van de banden', 'Reservewiel'],
            'trace_of_use': ['Krik'],
            'to_repair': [],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Verlichtimi: en signalisatie',
            'good': ['Kruislichten', 'Grootlichten', 'Mistlichten vooraan', 'Suoolementaire verlichting',
                     'Standlichten', 'Richtingaanwiizers', 'Alarrn(signaal)', 'Stoolichten', 'Nummerplaatverlichting'],
            'trace_of_use': ['Krik'],
            'to_repair': ['Mistachterlicht', 'Achteruitri ilicht', 'Enkeltonige claxon',
                          'instrurnentenbord : verlichting en lampjes'],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Uitrustinegen',
            'good': ['Zetels', 'Gordels', 'Stuurwiel', 'Brandblusser', 'Verbanddoos', 'Airconditioning',
                     'Audio installatie ( ootioneel)', 'Elektrische ruiten', 'Centrale vergrendeling'],
            'trace_of_use': ['Ruitenwisser en ruitensproeier vooraan', 'Binnen- en buitenspiegels',
                             'Alarmsvsteem ( optioneel)'],
            'to_repair': ['Ooendak', 'Reservewielhouder + druk van het reservewiel',
                          'Aanhangwagenkopoeling ( ootioneel', 'Gevarendriehoek'],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Beglazing - carrosserie',
            'good': ['Voorruit en beglazing', 'Deuren en kofferdeksel', 'Motorkao', 'Soatborden',
                     'Bumpers -afdekplaten', 'Reflectoren achterlichten', 'Laadbak -cabine (bedrijfsvoertuig'],
            'trace_of_use': [],
            'to_repair': [],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Remmen - stuurinrichting',
            'good': ['Bedriifsrem', 'Handrem', 'Remvloeistofreservoir', 'Hoofdremcilinder', 'Rembekrachtiging',
                     'Sturbekrachtiging', 'Staal van rem- en stuurleidingen', 'Vloeistofreservoir stuurbekrachtiging',
                     'Remblokken', 'Remschijven', 'Remzadels', 'Remkrachtverdelers', 'Handremkabel', 'Stuurhuis',
                     'Reactiestangen stuurinrichting'],
            'trace_of_use': [],
            'to_repair': [],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Verbindingen met het wegdek - assen',
            'good': ['Voortrein', 'Achtertrein', 'Veren', 'Staal schokdempers', 'Wielnaven', 'Wiellagerhuis',
                     'Wiellagers', 'Driehoeksophanging', 'Reactiestangen', 'Silentblocs', 'Kogelgewrichten',
                     'Stabilisatiestang( en)', 'Silentblocs motor en versnellingsbak'],
            'trace_of_use': [],
            'to_repair': [],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Bouw - carrosserie',
            'good': ['Langsliggers - dwarsliggers', 'Bodem', 'Hulpchassis', 'Wieldoorgangen', 'Stijlen', 'Kale carrosserie', 'Chassis', 'Onderziide'],
            'trace_of_use': ['Kogelgewrichten stuurinrichting'],
            'to_repair': [],
        },
        {
            'name': 'Verontreiniging;',
            'good': ['Uitlaatgassentest'],
            'trace_of_use': [],
            'to_repair': [],
        }
    ]
```

In my template I try to loop through that list as follows:

```
{% for description in car.description %}
    <div class="wrapper width-50 {% cycle 'pad-rgh pull-left' 'pad-lft pull-right' %}">
        <div class="title-description text-center clear-float">
            <div class="width-10 pad-half secondary-bg">{{ forloop.counter }}</div>
            <div class="width-55 text-left pad-half primary-bg">{{ description.name }}</div>
            <div class="width-10 pad-half secondary-bg">1</div>
            <div class="width-10 pad-half secondary-bg bord-hor">2</div>
            <div class="width-10 pad-half secondary-bg">3</div>
        </div>

        {% for good in description.good %}
            <div class="content">
                <div class="item-description clear-float">
                    <div class="width-55 pad-half" style="margin-left: 10%">{{ good }}</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">1</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for trace_of_use in description.trace_of_use %}
            <div class="content">
                <div class="item-description clear-float">
                    <div class="width-55 pad-half" style="margin-left: 10%">{{ trace_of_use }}</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">1</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for to_repair in description.to_repair %}
            <div class="content">
                <div class="item-description clear-float">
                    <div class="width-55 pad-half" style="margin-left: 10%">{{ to_repair }}</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="width-10 pad-half text-center">1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %} <div class="clear-float"></div> {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result that I get is as follows:

[image]

I want to show it without the white space between div's. Thus, like this:

[image]

Any advice how to do that?

Comment: maybe i'm missing this here, but are you wondering about the space inbetween the entire left side vs the entire right side? that gap inbetween them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do use the code below for reference, the only thing is that this organizes the divs from top to bottom and not from left to right like you showed it in your screenshot.

If this is important to you, masonry may be the best solution for you. Otherwise the code below should do it:

Masonry link: http://masonry.desandro.com/

```css
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.row {
 -moz-column-width: 12em;
 -webkit-column-width: 12em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap:1em;
 padding: 1em; 
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom:  1em;
 width:  100%; 
}

.type  {
 background: #ccc;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 position:relative;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="type">
        <h4>1</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tortor felis, venenatis sit amet justo eu, accumsan commodo nisl. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
   </div>
    </div> <!-- item -->
    
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="type">
        <h4>2</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tortor felis, venenatis sit amet justo eu.
      </div>
     
    </div> <!-- item -->
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="type">
        <h4>3</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
     
    </div> <!-- item -->
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="type">
        <h4>4</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tortor felis, venenatis sit amet justo eu, accumsan commodo nisl.
      </div>
     
    </div> <!-- item -->
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="type">
        <h4>5</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
     
    </div> <!-- item -->
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you do it with my example. It's a bit easier if the content is static.